# hours calculation error in excel 2010

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I need to calculate the hours between 2 time in excel. I have 2 questions as follows:

I did the following:

**(1)**

```
A1 = 10am
B1 = 9am
```

my formula: `B1-A1`
t gives me a ####### answer. how to resolve this?

**(2)** 
if i use this formula:

```
=INT((B1-A1)*24))
```

it gives me a -1 answer which is correct. 
However, if I change another time, e.g.

```
A1 = 3pm
B1 = 4pm
```

the answer is 0, it doesn't return 1 as the answer. Why is that so? 
But if I put B1 = 5pm, it returns 2 as the answer

can help to advise this?

Comment: How should Excel guess that `"3pm"` is equal to `Data of type DateTime with value 15:00:00`? Did you specify the cell format?

Comment: You should use only B1-A1, if values are valid times the answer will be correct and will use the same format. This, of course, will not work if the answer is a negative one. (time cannot be negative) If you want to use negative values use a in if and subtract like @simoco

Comment: @user2715525, if you'd format your result cell as `Number`, you could simply use `=24*(B1-A1)`

Answer (score 4):

Date/time in excel are actually numbers. 1 unit is equivalent to 1 day, so 1 hour would have a value of 1/24.

Negative time is not possible in excel, and that's why you get `####` when you have a negative time. You already found a way to resolve this in your question, by using `=INT((B1-A1)*24))`, except that the `INT` is not really necessary unless you *want* to have rounding.

As for your second question this has to do with excel not handling 'exact' fractions. You actually get `0.9999999` as the result and passing through `INT` makes this a `0`. Just remove the `INT` and you'll get `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Column A: initial time (format as h:mm)
- Column B: final time (format as h:mm)
- Column C: result (format as h:mm)

Don't forget to format the cells as customs format.

=IF(A1="",0,IF(B1>A1,B1-A1,B1+1-A1))

Hope it helps